# Jboss webservice error using topdown approach

Tags: jbossws

I started creating a sample webservice using top-down approach in jboss4.2.2 GA.

From the wsdl, i generated stubs using wsconsume

I created a new java class: `SalesTaxImpl` implementing the interface in the generated stub. Configured `@WebService` with `endpointInterface`, `portname`, `wsdllocation`.

My war application has the following:

- WEB-INF/classes/
- WEB-INF/wsdl/SalesTaxService.wsdl
- WEB-INF/web.xml

In web.xml i have,

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SalesTax</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hp.np.ws.SalesTaxImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SalesTax</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tax</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

After placing the war in `<JBOSS_HOME>/server/default/deploy` path, i am getting the following error:

```
19:25:05,046 INFO  [DefaultEndpointRegistry] register: jboss.ws:context=JbossWST
opDown,endpoint=SalesTax
19:25:05,078 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/JbossWSTopDown, warUrl=.../
tmp/deploy/tmp13893JbossWSTopDown-exp.war/
19:25:05,171 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/C:/jboss-4.2
.2.GA/server/default/deploy/JbossWSTopDown.war
org.jboss.ws.WSException: Cannot build meta data: Cannot get URL for: WEB-INF/ws
dl/SalesTaxService.wsdl
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.bu
ildWebServiceMetaData(JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder.java:207)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.setupP
roviderOrWebService(JAXWSServerMetaDataBuilder.java:50)
```

I tried giving different combination, but no luck

Comment: Why are you starting a new project on JBoss 4.x? It's old and out of date, especially for web services.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But project requirements warrants the use of jboss 4.2.2 :( ..

Comment: Pls let me know if you have any ideas about error resolution..Thanks in advance

Comment: issue is resolved. Actually wsdl was not placed under WEB-INF.